# Malloc/realloc only works with useless printf

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, malloc, realloc

Im trying to tokenizer the argv by the character '|' and return pointers for each command separately, for example:

If `argv = "./a ls -a '|' grep png"`, I need that `cmd[0]` point to `ls` and `cmd[1]` point to `grep`. I wrote the code below, but, somehow, only works with a useless printf, on line 20:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<unistd.h>

char*** tokenizer(char** command, int argc){
    int token_amount = 0;

    char ***cmd = (char***) malloc(1 *sizeof(char**));
    cmd[0] = &command[0];

    for(int i = 0; i < argc; i += 1){
        //For each founded '|', cmd receives the next position of command
        if(!strcmp(command[i], "|")){
            token_amount += 1;
            cmd = realloc(cmd, token_amount *sizeof(*cmd));
            cmd[token_amount] = &command[i + 1];
            command[i] = NULL;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    command[argc] = NULL;
    return cmd;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    char **command, ***cmd = NULL;

    //command doesn't receives the name of the executable
    command = &argv[1];
    cmd = tokenizer(command, argc - 1);
    
    //Testing
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i += 1){
        printf("%s\n", cmd[i][0]);
    }
    //Testing
    execvp(cmd[0][0], cmd[0]);
    
    return 0;
}
```

How can I avoid this printf?

Comment: "useless printf" is usually "helping" in case the code contains *undefined behavior*. Unfortunately it is pretty hard to spot one in the code containing three star pointers.

Comment: `cmd[token_amount]` is out of bounds, the last valid index is `token_amount - 1`.

Comment: The first `realloc` does not increase the memory size, since `token_amount ` is `1`.

Comment: Thank you for the tips. Even correcting the out of bounds error, it still didn't work. And about the first realloc, that was the problem! I didn’t know that, necessarily, realloc should resize in every step, in order for it to work perfectly. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem with these two lines:

```
cmd = realloc(cmd, token_amount *sizeof(*cmd));
cmd[token_amount] = &command[i + 1];
```

After calling `realloc`, the valid indices into `cmd` are `0` through `token_amount-1`.  But the very next line uses `token_amount` as an index, which is out of bounds.  You probably want to use `token_amount-1` as the index.

Comment: Even correcting the out of bounds error, it still didn't work. The problem was realloc at the first increment, that does not increase the memory size! I didn’t know that, necessarily, realloc should resize in every step, in order for it to work perfectly. Thank you for the tips!